# gnu ldでグローバル変数の配置順を指定する方法

Tags: c, gcc

こんにちは。

gcc (H8系) で組込向けにプログラムを作ろうとしています (gcc:8.3.0, binutils:2.32, Newlib:3.1.0)。
ビルドは出来たのですが、mapファイルを見たところ、グローバル変数が定義順に並んでいません。アセンブリコードを見たところ、定義順に記述されていたので、おそらくリンカが配置を最適化したのだと考えました。

それでは、と、リンカスクリプトで独自のセクションを用意しました。今度はバラバラの順序にはならなかったのですが、なぜか定義とは逆順に割り当てられていました。

リンカスクリプトの定義:

```
.nonvolatile : {
    *(.nonvolatile)
} > ram
```

変数の定義:

```
#define NV_SECT __attribute__((section(".nonvolatile")))
double a NV_SECT;
unsigned int b NV_SECT;
unsigned char c NV_SECT;
```

メモリ配置:

```
        0x0000000000400000                _c
        0x0000000000400002                _b
        0x0000000000400004                _a
```

質問ですが、gnu ld で変数のメモリへの配置を定義順にするには、何が必要なんでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

、、とは書いたものの、
[GCC compiles EEPROM addresses in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410303/gcc-compiles-eeprom-addresses-in-reverse-order)
を見る限り、駄目っぽいですかね、、？

いまのところ、解決策としては、

1. 構造体にまとめる: 上記サイトの解決案
2. 変数ごとに番地を指定する: 人間リンカ
3. 変数ごとにセクションを区切る: "nonvolatile.a" のように。人間リンカよりはまし。できることは確認

でしょうか。なにかうまい設定があればよいのですが、、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ウチでは [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) でなく Renesas H8 C/C++ Compiler を使っていますが

実メモリ上の配置順ってそんなに重要ですか？ ウチでは H8CC/SHCC の `-stuff` コンパイルオプションを使って、定義順でなくサイズ別に変数を配置していて困ったことはありません（むしろパディングの無駄領域が排除できて万々歳っす）。定義順が重要になるとしたら通信電文を直接変数に保持したい場合くらいしか思いつかないのですが、それならば 1. の通り `struct` にしちゃうのが自然でしょう。これもバイトオーダーやビットオーダーが吸収できないとハマるのであまりお勧めできないですけど。

というわけで「なぜ」配置順を維持したいのかわからないと積極的に提案できないんですが、とりあえず 1. 以外に方法はないでしょう（ 3. してもリンク時のオブジェクトファイル指定順などで順序が変わるはずなので無駄な努力っぽい）

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) の場合 `struct`/`class` のメンバ変数が宣言順に配置されることすら決まっていませんし、 ICE でメモリダンプを取って変数の値を確認するだけなら変数定義順でなくても一向にかまわないし、と難しい根拠ならいくらでも挙げられますけど、配置順にする必然は挙げにくくて提案しづらいです。

Comment: C++でも（アクセスコントロールが同じであれば）宣言順に配置されることが定められていますよ。 -- Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so
that later members have higher addresses within a class object.

Comment: はい、アクセスコントロール `public:` や `private:` が挟まると不連続になってよいので、宣言順になるとは限りません。

Comment: (もともと別のマイコンで、) SRAMをバッテリバックアップして、そこに設定値を保存しているシステムがあり、同じ仕組みを検討していました。EEPROM/Flashデバイスがあれば、そこまで頑張る必要はないかもしれませんが、、

Comment: GNU ld のドキュメントには "Normally, the linker will place files and sections matched by wildcards in the order in which they are seen during the link." と書いてあるのに、、

Comment: なお、SORT_NONEは "SORT_NONE disables section sorting by ignoring the command-line section sorting option." コマンドラインのオプションを無効にするだけのようで、効果ありませんでした。

Comment: とりあえず、".nonvolatile.varname" セクションを一つのファイルでのみ記述すれば定義順に配置できたので、3を使ってみます。ありがとうございました。